# How to handle unused parameter from api in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api

**My requirement for Dropdown only name and id, if I didn't include all parameters to file id didn't parse the object. it throws gson error.
How to create an object to handle this response for the unwanted parameters from API response in Flutter.**

```
 import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
    import 'dart:convert';
    
    class Customer {
        Customer({
            @required this.data,
            @required this.status,
        });
    
        List<Datum> data;
        int status;
    
        factory Customer.fromRawJson(String str) => Customer.fromJson(json.decode(str));
    
        String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());
    
        factory Customer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Customer(
            data: json["data"] == null ? null : List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
            status: json["status"] == null ? null : json["status"],
        );
    
        Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            "data": data == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
            "status": status == null ? null : status,
        };
    }
    
    class Datum {
        Datum({
            @required this.id,
            @required this.name,
            @required this.contactPersonName,
            @required this.mobileNo,
            @required this.whatsAppNo,
            @required this.user,
            @required this.address,
            @required this.gstNo,
            @required this.creaditPeriod,
            @required this.note,
            @required this.created,
            @required this.modified,
            @required this.contactPersonEmail,
        });
    
        String id;
        String name;
        dynamic contactPersonName;
        dynamic mobileNo;
        dynamic whatsAppNo;
        dynamic user;
        dynamic address;
        dynamic gstNo;
        dynamic creaditPeriod;
        dynamic note;
        dynamic created;
        dynamic modified;
        dynamic contactPersonEmail;
    
        factory Datum.fromRawJson(String str) => Datum.fromJson(json.decode(str));
    
        String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());
    
        factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
            id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
            name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
            contactPersonName: json["contactPersonName"],
            mobileNo: json["mobileNo"],
            whatsAppNo: json["whatsAppNo"],
            user: json["user"],
            address: json["address"],
            gstNo: json["gstNo"],
            creaditPeriod: json["creaditPeriod"],
            note: json["note"],
            created: json["created"],
            modified: json["modified"],
            contactPersonEmail: json["contactPersonEmail"],
        );
    
        Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            "id": id == null ? null : id,
            "name": name == null ? null: name,
            "contactPersonName": contactPersonName,
            "mobileNo": mobileNo,
            "whatsAppNo": whatsAppNo,
            "user": user,
            "address": address,
            "gstNo": gstNo,
            "creaditPeriod": creaditPeriod,
            "note": note,
            "created": created,
            "modified": modified,
            "contactPersonEmail": contactPersonEmail,
        };
    }
```

**Any idea how to create small object with id and name parameters only.**

Answer (score 1):

Just include the parameters you need from the json to the Model.
For example:

```
  class Datum { 
final String name;
final String id;
Datum({this.name,this.id});
}
```